# Duplicates report

Tags: reporting

Does anyone knows if there is a way or app/tool that:
Create new records when importing into SFDC
Block duplicates before they go into SFDC
Create a report that I can extract to another file (e.g excel)? with all the duplicates that were not imported into SFDC?
Thanks!

Comment: DupeCatcher is a free one. I've used DupeBlocker which is paid but quite effective and is configurable.

Answer (score 1):

For blocking duplicate data, you might try [DupeBlocker by CRMFusion](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016cMzEAI), [DataTrim by d2b International](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016cJPEAY), or others from the [AppExchange](http://www.appexchange.com/). There are costs for some of them, others are free. Note that I have not evaluated any of the mentioned software packages, nor do I, or have ever, worked for any of the companies mentioned, and therefore cannot make any recommendations.

It's also possible to write your own deduplication tool. The important thing here is that the tool should leverage the standard error reporting functionality of Apex Code. This will allow you to use tools like the [Excel Connector](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_Excel_Connector) or the [Apex Data Loader](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Data_Loader) to capture errors. The Excel Connector will highlight any error conditions when inserting or updating data with yellow cells, and the Apex Data Loader will make an "errorNNN.csv" file (NNN are numbers), which you can review in any standard spreadsheet application.

Comment: Thank for the info. What I need is something similar to DataLoader: an uploading, easy-to-use tool that reports an error file.

Comment: What happens is that users will be upserting data and they should have an ID record to perform the update action. However, they wont' have an ID so new records will be created so that duplicates will come to SFDC. They idea is to upsert records without an ID, match them by a custom field with existing records, and if any match is found, the upload of that particular records would failed. That failed record would indicate there is a duplicate. And all duplicates should go to a list that I can download or extract.

Comment: Is there any app that provides this functionality? Maybe writing some code?

Comment: I think you're looking more for a "dup marker" app so that the duplicates can be reported upon. You can't report on data that's not in the system, so outright "failing" a record save would prevent you from downloading or extracting a list. As I stated, the Data Loader stores your failed records in a file that you can review. Also, using upsert is probably not a good idea, since your goal is to find out if there are duplicates. Upsert will update an existing record if it finds a match instead of "failing" to save.